# Is there a difference between "dubas, ke" and "dubas, ĉu"?

Tags: word-difference

Both seems to be used often. Zamenhof uzis ambaŭ:

> - neniu dubos, ke konstanta regulo estas mil fojojn pli bona
> - mi dubas, ĉu troviĝos iu

Is there now a difference in meaning, or is one better than the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only use the word *ĉu* here when you want to emphasize uncertainty. Then it means something like *sin demandi ĉu*.

> *Neniu dubas, ke tio estas fakto.* No one doubts that it is a fact.
>
> *Li dubis ke mi aĝis nur ok.* He doubted that I was only eight. (He suspected not.)
>
> *Li dubis ĉu mi aĝis nur ok.* He had doubts about me being eight. (He continued to wonder about it.)

I base this on Zamenhof's *Lingva Respondo 21-a* ("Pri la vorto *ĉu*").

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Andrew's answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/1085/1576) and would like to point out that a verbatim translation to English or German gets almost the same meaning across, even if leading to non-idiomatic sentences.

Keeping the following translation in mind can thus help to remember which one means what:

- *ke* → en:*that*, de:*dass*
- *ĉu* → en:*whether* (or en:*if*), de:*ob*

> *Li dubis, **ke** mi aĝis nur ok.*

> He doubted **that** I was only eight.

> Er bezeifelte, **dass** ich erst acht war.

---

> *Li dubis, **ĉu** mi aĝis nur ok.*

> He doubted **whether** I was only eight.

or more colloquially:

> He doubted **if** I was only eight.

(Both a bit strange. It'd probably be more natural to use the verb "to wonder" in English, but still with *whether* or *if*. It conveys a slightly different meaning though.)

> Er bezeifelte, **ob** ich erst acht war.

(Same here. *Er fragte sich, ob ich erst acht war.* would be more natural, but may imply that he kept that doubt to himself, while de:*bezweifeln* –like eo:*dubi*, en:*doubt* and en:*wonder*– leaves open whether the doubt was uttered or not.